# Returning an Observable inside a resolved promise

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Trying to return an `Observable`.
How should I go about this?

```
  get(url) : Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.SetAuthorizationHeader(headers).then(() => { // Resolving a promise
      return this.http.get(url, { // <-- I need to return the Observable from here
          headers: headers
      });
    });
  }
```

Consumed (not working):

```
public GetInfo() : Observable<any> {
    return this.authHttpClient.get(this.constants.api_base + "/users/info")
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Who is the "obseviee" .. the one for the promisse that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to return `this.SetAuthorizationHeader(headers)` method, so on resolve of `SetAuthorizationHeader` method, it will return `http.get` call observable.

> Here you need to remove `Observable<any>` from get method return type,
>   as actually it is going to return `Promise` object.

**Code**

```
get(url) : any {
    let headers = new Headers();
    //return promise here to continue chain & return inner observable.
    return this.SetAuthorizationHeader(headers).then(() => { // Resolving a promise
      return this.http.get(url, { // <-- I need to return the Observable from here
          headers: headers
      });
    }).map(data => data.json());
}
```

**Consumption**

```
public GetInfo() : any { //here also it will be any, because you are returning `authHttpClient.get` at the end
    return this.authHttpClient.get(this.constants.api_base + "/users/info"));
}
```

**Get Info Consumption**

```
this.user.GetInfo().then(obs => 
    obs.subscribe(
      user => { alert(JSON.stringify(user)); }, 
     (error) => { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); }
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. If I remove the `Observable<any>` method return type then I cannot use `.map()` somewhere else in the code. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: @user1027620 does it work with `Observable<any>`? I don't think so

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately, how can I consume this `get()` method?

Comment: try this `this.service.get(url).then((observable)=> observable.map(data => data.json()).subscribe(
 (data) = console.log("Data returned by observable", data)
))`

Comment: This isn't working for me: 
    `public GetInfo() : Observable<any> {
        return this.authHttpClient.get(this.constants.api_base + "/users/info")
            .then((observable) => observable.map(data => data.json()));
    }` returns: Unhandled Promise rejection: this.user.GetInfo()
            .subscribe is not a function. (In 'this.user.GetInfo()

Comment: @user1027620 what error you are getting? I'd say then move `.map` inside `get` method of service, where you are returning `this.http.get(...).map(data=> data.json())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121480/discussion-between-user1027620-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: I've added the errors i am getting in chat. Appreciate if you can take a look. Thanks again.

Comment: It's exploding when running this code: `this.user.GetInfo()
      .subscribe(user => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(user));
      }, (error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });` -> `EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.user.GetInfo()`
            `.subscribe is not a function. (In 'this.user.GetInfo()`

Comment: The return type of the code is Promise<Observable<any>> which doesn't have the subscribe function, and that's why we need to add .then(obs => obs.subscribe(... to the consumption. Is there a way to have the code return  Observable<any> to avoid adding this code everywhere the method is consumed?

Answer (score 2):

Pankaj Parker's works but the return type is `Promise<Observable<any>>`. That's why the extra `.then((obs) => obs.subscribe(...))` is needed.

You can avoid that by transforming your promise to an observable and use `concatMap` to combine the two.

With concatMap you can control the order of the observables, so the observable that sets the authorization header is emitted before the http request.

**Code**

```
  get(url): any {
    let headers = new Headers();
    //transform promise to observable
    const authHeaderObservable = Observable.from(this.SetAuthorizationHeader(headers));

    return authHeaderObservable.concatMap(() => { //return the outer observable
      return this.http.get(url, { // <-- I need to return the inner Observable from here
        headers: headers
      }).map(data => data.json());
    })
  }
```

**Consumption**

```
public GetInfo() : any { //here also it will be any, because you are returning `authHttpClient.get` at the end
    return this.authHttpClient.get(this.constants.api_base + "/users/info"));
}
```

**Get Info Consumption**

```
this.user.GetInfo().subscribe(
      user => { alert(JSON.stringify(user)); }, 
     (error) => { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); }
);
```